# Convert a string to seconds with PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

I have string '6m15s' in PHP that I would like to convert in to time or ideally seconds. I am using the `strtotime()` function like:

```
$time = date('H:i:s', strtotime('6m15s'));
echo $time;
```

But all I get '01:00:00'. Is this possible to convert my string and if so what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: strtotime can do a lot of things, but it is NOT omniscient and can't convert EVERYTHING time-related. yank apart your string and use `mktime()` instead. `6m` is ambiguous anyways. 6 months? 6 minutes?

Comment: 6m15s is not a valid format to pass to strtotime()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [substr()](http://php.net/substr):

```
$string = '6m15s';
$minute = substr($string, 0, 1);
$second = substr($string, 2, 2);
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime("00:$minute:$second"));
// outputs 00:06:15
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the total number of seconds then something like:

```
preg_match('/((?<h>[\d]+)h)?((?<m>[\d]+)m)?((?<s>[\d]+)s?)/', $var, $m);

echo ($m['h']* 60 + $m['m']) * 60 + $m['s'];  // 375
```

This looks for hours as well, as in `1h6m15s`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the fix patterns then you can construct a method like:

```
function stringToSecondByPattern($subject, $pattern = '/(\d+)m(\d+)s/') {

    $matches = [];
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

    list($original, $minuets, $seconds) = $matches;

    $secondsSum = $seconds + ($minuets * 60);

    return $secondsSum;
}

print stringToSecondByPattern('6m15s');
```